# "Thou shalt not pass" and "You shall not pass" hybrid

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, personal-pronouns, thou-thee-thy

Is it technically incorrect grammar to make a hybrid of the well known statements: "Thou shalt not pass" and "You shall not pass"––this hybrid being: "You shalt not pass"?

From what I understand from not 100% trustworthy sources (Wikipedia), "Thou shalt not" is used by the KJV (Ten Commandments, etc.) and is Shakespearean English, whereas "Thou shall not" is the modern equivalent.

My question is (a) if the hybrid statement is grammatically correct, and (b) if "Thou shall not" truly is the grammatically correct equivalent of "Thou shalt not".

Comment: Yes. "You shalt not pass" and "Thou shall not pass" are as technically grammatically incorrect as sentences like "They is happy" or "It are good" would be. That said, most people don't know how to use the grammar of "thou/thee," "-(e)st" and "-(e)th" anyway. The "modern" equivalent of *Thou shalt not* is *You shall not* (actually, *shall* is also old-fashioned, so really *You will not* or *You must not*). But people know *Thou shalt not* fine, so why even bother changing it?

Comment: I don't imagine this would have anything to do with an impasse between flames of Anor and Udûn?

Comment: @tchrist , I was actually going to mention that in my title, but thought against it : )

Comment: For what its worth, the original Moses construction is "No (verbing-thou)."  So you could mimic it by " No passing, Thou **!** "

Comment: Then it would be ugly; but not wrong.

Comment: The real test is not whether something aligns with traditional grammar but whether or not it can be understood. "Thou shall" etc. is a bit awkward and quirky, but its meaning is still clear.

Comment: @sumelic Are you saying that *shalt* was the singular form? If so was it only used for second person?

Comment: @Tom: exactly. "Shalt" was the second person singular inflected form of "shall."

Comment: Saying *thou shall* instead of *thou shalt* is like saying *he do* instead of *he does* - obviously you can say it, but the question is whether or not you should.

Comment: In modern dialect, as in Yorkshire, ‘thou’ uses the third-person singular inflections: ‘thou has’, ‘thou does’, etc (but not ‘thou is’).  I haven't been able to find if this applies to modals, so maybe ‘thou shall’ really is agrammatical, but I think that the commenters here are too confident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**“You shalt” is not ‘correct’, nor is “Thou shall not”**

Putting aside the question of whether conjugation of verbs is a technically a *grammatical rule* or has some other status, in English, like many other languages, **different pronouns call for different verb forms**, and mixing them up often produces jarring and unnatural-sounding sentences that most would not consider correct.

For instance the verb 'to be' conjugates as follows in the present indicative:

- I **am**
- Thou **art** (obsolete in modern English and replaced by 'you' form)
- He/She/It **is**
- We **are**
- You **are**
- They **are**

These are sometimes referred to as the first, second, and third person singular and plural forms respectively.

Most verbs now only have two forms in the present tense: the form which is the same as the infinitive, and a he/she/it form (3rd person singular) which has an -s or -es on the end: **work/works**, **pass/passes**. A few verbs only have the one form (e.g. can).

However, when the 'thou' pronoun was in common use, many verbs also had a 'thou' form ending in -t, -st, or -est: e.g. **shalt**, **wilt**, **canst**.

Over time the 'you' form supplanted 'thou', and the 'thou' forms also all disappeared. They are recognised largely because they feature in older texts such as the KJV.